# How to transfer a database AND its users from one SQL Server to another?

Tags: sql-server

we have one db in an SQLServer instance that should be transferred to another instance (let's say `dbname="testdb"` with a user `testuser`).

This transfer works easily when we use SQL Server Management Studio (backup the database on the source machine and restore it on the target machine).

The problem is now that I can't connect with the `testuser` on the target machine. It's part of the db but not part of the SQL Server wide logins.

Now my question. How can I add the user from the db to the SQL Server logins?

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Cheers,
Helmut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What really helped me in the end was running the following SQL script (after restore)

```
USE testdb;
GO
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'testuser', NULL, 'testpwd';
GO
```

This "connects" the database user "testuser" to the server login "testuser". If no server login "testuser" exists a new one is created.

For documentation please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I used to face the same problem dear.
The Solution for his is You have to create login in server with the Statement below

Use [testdb]  --Your Database name

CREATE USER [testuser] FOR LOGIN [testuser]

here your [testuser] is your database user and  the second [testuser] your server login name and with this statement we mapped each other.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds similar to the solution I found. (s. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977114/how-to-transfer-a-database-and-its-users-from-one-sql-server-to-another/5988594#5988594)